# Custom shortcode for creating tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, shortcode

I am currently trying to create a shortcode for WordPress that creates tabs, I know there are available shortcodes.. But I am trying to learn how to write them myself.

Currently I am  generating the tab menu items, but i am stuck with placing the content in an entirely new div.

Front end Usage:

```
[tabs]
 [tab title="tab" active="y" id="home"]home[/tab]
 [tab title="tab2" active="n" id="about"]about[/tab]
 [tab title="tab3" active="n" id="help"]help[/tab]
[/tabs]
```

And then the code:

```
function tabs_group( $atts, $content = null ) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
    'id' => '',
    'class' => ''
    ), $atts));  

    $output  = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs '.$class.'"  ';

    if(!empty($id))
        $output .= 'id="'.$id.'"';

    $output .='>'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';

    return $output;  
}  

add_shortcode("tabs", "tabs_group");

function tab($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
    'id' => '',
    'title' => '',
    'active'=>'n' 
    ), $atts));  
    if(empty($id))
        $id = 'tab_item_'.rand(100,999);

    $output = '<li class="'.($active == 'y' ? 'active' :'').'">
                <a href="#'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>
                </li>';  
    $output .= '<div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane"  id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>
                </div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("tab", "tab");
```

it currently returns:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active">
                <a href="#home">tab</a>
                </li><div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane"  id="home">home</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="home">home</div>
                </div>
 <li class="">
                <a href="#about">tab2</a>
                </li><div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="about">about</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane"  id="about">about</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="about">about</div>
                </div>
 <li class="">
                <a href="#help">tab3</a>
                </li><div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="help">help</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane"  id="help">help</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="help">help</div>
                </div>
</ul>
```

and i need it to return:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs "  >
 <li class="active">
    <a href="#home">tab</a>
 </li>
 <li class="">
    <a href="#about">tab2</a>
 </li>
 <li class="">
    <a href="#help">tab3</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">blah</div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="about">blah</div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="help">blah</div>
</div>
```

I have added to the output, thank you Obmerk Kronen.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: you do not have the part of the divs in your content

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand?

Comment: you want your code to produce divs right ? where are they ?

Comment: In Your question you have added them in the wrong place , they should be added AFTER the UL is closed (as per your example of the wanted output )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to add your divs after `do_shortcode($content)` : while parsing `tab` shorcodes, you need to keep your divs somewhere to be able to output them after.

A **simple** way (**not nicest way**) for doing this could be using a global var, e.g. :

```
add_shortcode('tabs', 'tabs_group');
add_shortcode('tab', 'tab');

// this variable will hold your divs
$tabs_divs = '';

function tabs_group( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $tabs_divs;

    // reset divs
    $tabs_divs = '';

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        'id' => '',
        'class' => ''
    ), $atts));  

    $output = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs '.$class.'"  ';

    if(!empty($id))
        $output .= 'id="'.$id.'"';

    $output.='>'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
    $output.= '<div class="tab-content">'.$tabs_divs.'</div>';

    return $output;  
}  


function tab($atts, $content = null) {  
    global $tabs_divs;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        'id' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'active'=>'n' 
    ), $atts));  

    if(empty($id))
        $id = 'tab_item_'.rand(100,999);

    $activeClass = $active == 'y' ? 'active' :'';
    $output = '
        <li class="'.$activeClass.'">
            <a href="#'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>
        </li>
    ';

    $tabs_divs.= '<div class="tab-pane '.$activeClass.'" id="'.$id.'">'.$content.'</div>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, Your answered worked for me.. "not nicest way", like i am trying to learn and write good code... so is this a bad habit or?..

Comment: You should read this about using global var : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions

Answer (score 1):

you do not currently have the content part of the divs in your content

```
$output .= '<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="'.$id.'">'.$title.'</div>
 <div class="tab-pane"  id="'.$id.'">'.$title.'</div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$id.'">'.$title.'</div>
</div>'
```

Comment: Thank you, your post was very useful.. but it didn't solve the problem.. Please see Update.. :)

Comment: @Dawid van der Hoven - It obviously did not solve the problem, becasue you have put it in the wrong place :-). But since my comment and answer someone already pasted the same solution in a different flavor . You should have pasted my code in the other function.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, take a look carefully at my answer and you will see that it is really not the same 'in a different flavor'...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//  my shortcode look like this.
[tabgroup] 
    [tab title="Your title #1" class="active" ]
     Your Description here #1
    [/tab]  
    [tab title="Your title #2" ]  
     Your Description here  #2 
    [/tab]    
    [tab title="Your title #3" ]   
     Your Description here #3
    [/tab]    
[/tabgroup]

add_shortcode( 'tab', 'ease_tabs' );
function ease_tabs( $atts, $content ){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title' => 'Tab',
        'class' => false,
    ), $atts));

     $x = isset($GLOBALS['tab_count'])?$GLOBALS['tab_count']:0; 
     $GLOBALS['tab_count'] = isset($GLOBALS['tab_count'])?$GLOBALS['tab_count']:0;          

     $GLOBALS['tabs'][$GLOBALS['tabs_count']][$x] = array( 
            'title'     => $title   ,
            'class'     => $class   ,
            'content'   => $content ,
     );

     $GLOBALS['tab_count']++;

 }

add_shortcode( 'tabgroup', 'ease_tabgroup' );
function ease_tabgroup( $atts, $content ){

    if( isset( $GLOBALS['tabs_count'] ) )
      $GLOBALS['tabs_count']++;
    else
      $GLOBALS['tabs_count'] = 0;

    do_shortcode( $content ); 

    if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'][$GLOBALS['tabs_count']] ) ){

        $tabs=array();
        $panes=array();

        foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'][$GLOBALS['tabs_count']] as $tab ){

        $panes_class  = ( !empty($tab["class"]) &&  $tab['class'] == "active" ) ? 'tab-pane active' : 'tab-pane';
        $__title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9._\-]/', '', strtolower($tab['title'])  );     
        $tabs[] = '<li  role="presentation" class="'.$tab['class'].'" >
                        <a href="#'.$__title.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$tab['title'].'</a>
                  </li>';
        $panes[] = sprintf( '<div class="%s" id="%s"> %s </div>',$panes_class, $__title, $tab['content']  );

        }


        $return = "\n".'<div role="tabpanel">
                            <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">'
                                .implode( "\n", $tabs ).
                            '</ul>'."\n".
                            '<div class="tab-content">'
                                    .implode( "\n", $panes ).
                            '</div>
                        </div>'."\n";       
    }   
    return do_shortcode( sprintf('<div class="tp-tabs"> %s </div>',  $return));
}
```

[wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)[shortcode](/questions/tagged/shortcode)

Comment: Please include some detail in your answer about what the cause of the problem is, and how your code solves it.